# Некорректная работа WIFI адаптера TP-LINK TL-WN727N в Debian

Tags: debian, железо

Подключил данное устройство к ПК с Debian buster/sid(Debian testing в данный момент), установил драйвер(mt7601u) и wirmware `aptitude intsall firmware-misc-nonfree firmware-realtek`, но подключится к точке доступа не удалось, список их доступен, а вот подключение не происходит.
Вывод `lsusb | grep 7601`:

```
Bus 001 Device 013: ID 148f:7601 Ralink Technology, Corp. MT7601U Wireless Adapter
```

Вывод `uname -r`:

```
4.12.0-1-amd64
```

Часть вывода `lshw -C network`:

```
  *-network:0
       description: Wireless interface
       physical id: 2
       bus info: usb@1:10
       logical name: wlxd46e0e1f1528
       serial: 22:f9:ff:11:96:7c
       capabilities: ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=mt7601u driverversion=4.12.0-1-amd64 firmware=N/A link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
```

Вывод `lsmod`:

```
Module                  Size  Used by
rndis_host             16384  0
cdc_ether              16384  1 rndis_host
usbnet                 45056  2 rndis_host,cdc_ether
nls_utf8               16384  0
isofs                  40960  0
uas                    24576  0
usb_storage            69632  1 uas
bnep                   20480  2
fuse                   98304  3
nls_ascii              16384  1
nls_cp437              20480  1
vfat                   20480  1
fat                    65536  1 vfat
arc4                   16384  2
mt7601u               102400  0
mac80211              659456  1 mt7601u
cfg80211              593920  2 mac80211,mt7601u
joydev                 20480  0
eeepc_wmi              16384  0
mxm_wmi                16384  0
asus_wmi               28672  1 eeepc_wmi
sparse_keymap          16384  1 asus_wmi
evdev                  24576  13
serio_raw              16384  0
intel_rapl             20480  0
x86_pkg_temp_thermal    16384  0
hci_uart               98304  0
intel_powerclamp       16384  0
btbcm                  16384  1 hci_uart
coretemp               16384  0
btqca                  16384  1 hci_uart
btintel                16384  1 hci_uart
bluetooth             540672  11 hci_uart,btintel,btqca,bnep,btbcm
kvm_intel             196608  0
snd_hda_codec_hdmi     49152  1
ecdh_generic           24576  1 bluetooth
kvm                   577536  1 kvm_intel
irqbypass              16384  1 kvm
crct10dif_pclmul       16384  0
crc32_pclmul           16384  0
ghash_clmulni_intel    16384  0
intel_cstate           16384  0
intel_uncore          118784  0
pcspkr                 16384  0
intel_rapl_perf        16384  0
efi_pstore             16384  0
iTCO_wdt               16384  0
snd_hda_codec_realtek    90112  1
snd_hda_codec_generic    69632  1 snd_hda_codec_realtek
efivars                20480  1 efi_pstore
battery                20480  0
iTCO_vendor_support    16384  1 iTCO_wdt
intel_lpss_acpi        16384  0
intel_lpss             16384  1 intel_lpss_acpi
mfd_core               16384  1 intel_lpss
sg                     32768  0
rfkill                 24576  6 asus_wmi,bluetooth,cfg80211
wmi                    16384  2 asus_wmi,mxm_wmi
snd_hda_intel          40960  3
snd_hda_codec         126976  4 snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec_realtek
acpi_pad               24576  0
snd_hda_core           77824  5 snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec_realtek
snd_hwdep              16384  1 snd_hda_codec
snd_pcm               102400  4 snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_core,snd_hda_codec_hdmi
snd_timer              32768  1 snd_pcm
i915                 1269760  21
shpchp                 36864  0
mei_me                 40960  0
snd                    77824  14 snd_hda_intel,snd_hwdep,snd_hda_codec,snd_timer,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_pcm
soundcore              16384  1 snd
mei                    94208  1 mei_me
video                  40960  2 asus_wmi,i915
button                 16384  1 i915
drm_kms_helper        151552  1 i915
drm                   348160  6 i915,drm_kms_helper
i2c_algo_bit           16384  1 i915
acpi_als               16384  0
kfifo_buf              16384  1 acpi_als
industrialio           65536  2 acpi_als,kfifo_buf
parport_pc             28672  0
ppdev                  20480  0
lp                     20480  0
parport                49152  3 lp,parport_pc,ppdev
efivarfs               16384  1
ip_tables              24576  0
x_tables               36864  1 ip_tables
autofs4                40960  2
ext4                  593920  2
crc16                  16384  2 bluetooth,ext4
jbd2                  102400  1 ext4
crc32c_generic         16384  0
fscrypto               28672  1 ext4
ecb                    16384  0
mbcache                16384  1 ext4
dm_mod                114688  9
hid_generic            16384  0
usbhid                 49152  0
sd_mod                 49152  3
crc32c_intel           24576  4
aesni_intel           167936  0
aes_x86_64             20480  1 aesni_intel
crypto_simd            16384  1 aesni_intel
cryptd                 24576  3 crypto_simd,ghash_clmulni_intel,aesni_intel
glue_helper            16384  1 aesni_intel
psmouse               143360  0
ahci                   36864  2
libahci                32768  1 ahci
i2c_i801               24576  0
r8169                  81920  0
mii                    16384  2 r8169,usbnet
libata                233472  2 ahci,libahci
scsi_mod              212992  5 sd_mod,usb_storage,libata,uas,sg
xhci_pci               16384  0
xhci_hcd              208896  1 xhci_pci
usbcore               245760  9 rndis_host,usbnet,usbhid,usb_storage,mt7601u,cdc_ether,xhci_pci,uas,xhci_hcd
usb_common             16384  1 usbcore
fan                    16384  0
thermal                20480  0
i2c_hid                20480  0
hid                   118784  3 i2c_hid,hid_generic,usbhid
```

Вывод `dmesg | grep 7601`:

```
[    2.064050] usb 1-10: New USB device found, idVendor=148f, idProduct=7601
[    9.675851] mt7601u 1-10:1.0: ASIC revision: 76010001 MAC revision: 76010500
[    9.699453] mt7601u 1-10:1.0: Warning: unsupported EEPROM version 0d
[    9.699454] mt7601u 1-10:1.0: EEPROM ver:0d fae:00
[    9.699700] mt7601u 1-10:1.0: EEPROM country region 01 (channels 1-13)
[    9.956146] usbcore: registered new interface driver mt7601u
[   10.299466] mt7601u 1-10:1.0 wlxd46e0e1f1528: renamed from wlan0
[  671.837363] mt7601u: disagrees about version of symbol module_layout
[  678.803132] mt7601u: disagrees about version of symbol module_layout
[ 1827.135678] mt7601u 1-10:1.0: Error: MCU response pre-completed!
[ 1827.150595] mt7601u 1-10:1.0: Warning: unsupported EEPROM version 0d
[ 1827.150598] mt7601u 1-10:1.0: EEPROM ver:0d fae:00
[ 1827.150842] mt7601u 1-10:1.0: EEPROM country region 01 (channels 1-13)
[ 2209.540804] mt7601u 1-10:1.0: Error: RX urb failed:-71
[ 2209.540855] mt7601u 1-10:1.0: Error: RX urb failed:-71
[ 2209.540887] mt7601u 1-10:1.0: Error: RX urb failed:-71
[ 2209.540967] mt7601u 1-10:1.0: Error: RX urb failed:-71
[ 2209.541006] mt7601u 1-10:1.0: Error: RX urb failed:-71
[ 2209.541087] mt7601u 1-10:1.0: Error: RX urb failed:-71
[ 2209.541126] mt7601u 1-10:1.0: Error: RX urb failed:-71
[ 2209.541207] mt7601u 1-10:1.0: Error: RX urb failed:-71
[ 2209.541285] mt7601u 1-10:1.0: Error: RX urb failed:-71
[ 2209.541365] mt7601u 1-10:1.0: Error: RX urb failed:-71
[ 2209.541446] mt7601u 1-10:1.0: Error: RX urb failed:-71
[ 2209.555877] mt7601u 1-10:1.0: Warning: TX DMA did not stop!
[ 2213.559746] mt7601u 1-10:1.0: Warning: MAC TX did not stop!
[ 2215.963724] mt7601u 1-10:1.0: Warning: MAC RX did not stop!
[ 2215.963727] mt7601u 1-10:1.0: Warning: RX DMA did not stop!
[ 3387.319280] usb 1-10: New USB device found, idVendor=148f, idProduct=7601
[ 3387.579480] mt7601u 1-10:1.0: ASIC revision: 76010001 MAC revision: 76010500
[ 3387.605496] mt7601u 1-10:1.0: firmware: direct-loading firmware mt7601u.bin
[ 3387.605506] mt7601u 1-10:1.0: Firmware Version: 0.1.00 Build: 7640 Build time: 201302052146____
[ 3388.023844] mt7601u 1-10:1.0: Warning: unsupported EEPROM version 0d
[ 3388.023848] mt7601u 1-10:1.0: EEPROM ver:0d fae:00
[ 3388.024065] mt7601u 1-10:1.0: EEPROM country region 01 (channels 1-13)
[ 3388.244465] mt7601u 1-10:1.0 wlxd46e0e1f1528: renamed from wlan0
```

Вывод `systemctl -u NetworkManager` после попытки подключения к точке доступа:

```
вер 14 13:46:10 myuser NetworkManager[1495]: <info>  [1505385970.4181] device (wlxd46e0e1f1528): Activation: starting connection 'mywifi' (5e961d46-56a6-48ff-ad6d-6e494f4d27e9)
вер 14 13:46:10 myuser NetworkManager[1495]: <info>  [1505385970.4190] audit: op="connection-activate" uuid="5e961d46-56a6-48ff-ad6d-6e494f4d27e9" name="mywifi" pid=958 uid=1000 result="success"
вер 14 13:46:10 myuser NetworkManager[1495]: <info>  [1505385970.4191] device (wlxd46e0e1f1528): state change: disconnected -> prepare (reason 'none', internal state 'managed')
вер 14 13:46:10 myuser NetworkManager[1495]: <info>  [1505385970.4192] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTING
вер 14 13:46:10 myuser NetworkManager[1495]: <info>  [1505385970.4233] device (wlxd46e0e1f1528): set-hw-addr: reset MAC address to D4:6E:0E:1F:15:28 (preserve)
вер 14 13:46:10 myuser NetworkManager[1495]: <info>  [1505385970.4419] device (wlxd46e0e1f1528): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none', internal state 'managed')
вер 14 13:46:10 myuser NetworkManager[1495]: <info>  [1505385970.4420] device (wlxd46e0e1f1528): Activation: (wifi) access point 'mywifi' has security, but secrets are required.
вер 14 13:46:10 myuser NetworkManager[1495]: <info>  [1505385970.4420] device (wlxd46e0e1f1528): state change: config -> need-auth (reason 'none', internal state 'managed')
вер 14 13:46:10 myuser NetworkManager[1495]: <info>  [1505385970.4530] device (wlxd46e0e1f1528): state change: need-auth -> prepare (reason 'none', internal state 'managed')
вер 14 13:46:10 myuser NetworkManager[1495]: <info>  [1505385970.4544] device (wlxd46e0e1f1528): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none', internal state 'managed')
вер 14 13:46:10 myuser NetworkManager[1495]: <info>  [1505385970.4550] device (wlxd46e0e1f1528): Activation: (wifi) connection 'mywifi' has security, and secrets exist.  No new secrets needed.
вер 14 13:46:10 myuser NetworkManager[1495]: <info>  [1505385970.4553] Config: added 'ssid' value 'mywifi'
вер 14 13:46:10 myuser NetworkManager[1495]: <info>  [1505385970.4555] Config: added 'scan_ssid' value '1'
вер 14 13:46:10 myuser NetworkManager[1495]: <info>  [1505385970.4557] Config: added 'key_mgmt' value 'WPA-PSK'
вер 14 13:46:10 myuser NetworkManager[1495]: <info>  [1505385970.4559] Config: added 'psk' value '<hidden>'
вер 14 13:46:10 myuser NetworkManager[1495]: <info>  [1505385970.4688] device (wlxd46e0e1f1528): supplicant interface state: inactive -> scanning
вер 14 13:46:11 myuser NetworkManager[1495]: <info>  [1505385971.4945] device (wlxd46e0e1f1528): supplicant interface state: scanning -> authenticating
вер 14 13:46:16 myuser NetworkManager[1495]: <info>  [1505385976.5156] device (wlxd46e0e1f1528): supplicant interface state: authenticating -> disconnected
вер 14 13:46:16 myuser NetworkManager[1495]: <info>  [1505385976.6157] device (wlxd46e0e1f1528): supplicant interface state: disconnected -> scanning
вер 14 13:46:17 myuser NetworkManager[1495]: <info>  [1505385977.6402] device (wlxd46e0e1f1528): supplicant interface state: scanning -> authenticating
вер 14 13:46:22 myuser NetworkManager[1495]: <info>  [1505385982.6634] device (wlxd46e0e1f1528): supplicant interface state: authenticating -> disconnected
вер 14 13:46:23 myuser NetworkManager[1495]: <info>  [1505385983.1639] device (wlxd46e0e1f1528): supplicant interface state: disconnected -> scanning
вер 14 13:46:24 myuser NetworkManager[1495]: <info>  [1505385984.1800] device (wlxd46e0e1f1528): supplicant interface state: scanning -> authenticating
вер 14 13:46:29 myuser NetworkManager[1495]: <info>  [1505385989.2072] device (wlxd46e0e1f1528): supplicant interface state: authenticating -> disconnected
вер 14 13:46:30 myuser NetworkManager[1495]: <info>  [1505385990.2083] device (wlxd46e0e1f1528): supplicant interface state: disconnected -> scanning
вер 14 13:46:31 myuser NetworkManager[1495]: <info>  [1505385991.2365] device (wlxd46e0e1f1528): supplicant interface state: scanning -> authenticating
вер 14 13:46:36 myuser NetworkManager[1495]: <warn>  [1505385996.1975] device (wlxd46e0e1f1528): Activation: (wifi) association took too long, failing activation
вер 14 13:46:36 myuser NetworkManager[1495]: <info>  [1505385996.1976] device (wlxd46e0e1f1528): state change: config -> failed (reason 'ssid-not-found', internal state 'managed')
вер 14 13:46:36 myuser NetworkManager[1495]: <info>  [1505385996.1980] manager: NetworkManager state is now DISCONNECTED
вер 14 13:46:36 myuser NetworkManager[1495]: <warn>  [1505385996.2012] device (wlxd46e0e1f1528): Activation: failed for connection 'mywifi'
вер 14 13:46:36 myuser NetworkManager[1495]: <info>  [1505385996.2022] device (wlxd46e0e1f1528): state change: failed -> disconnected (reason 'none', internal state 'managed')
вер 14 13:46:36 myuser NetworkManager[1495]: <info>  [1505385996.2229] device (wlxd46e0e1f1528): set-hw-addr: set MAC address to 56:E5:39:FA:59:DC (scanning)
вер 14 13:46:36 myuser NetworkManager[1495]: <warn>  [1505385996.2611] sup-iface[0x7f48440020a0,wlxd46e0e1f1528]: connection disconnected (reason -3)
вер 14 13:46:36 myuser NetworkManager[1495]: <info>  [1505385996.2613] device (wlxd46e0e1f1528): supplicant interface state: authenticating -> disconnected
```

Вывод `dmesg` после поопытки подключения к точке доступа:

```
[ 4695.971702] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlxd46e0e1f1528: link is not ready
[ 4696.986767] wlxd46e0e1f1528: authenticate with 94:0c:6d:f7:66:b4
[ 4697.015761] wlxd46e0e1f1528: send auth to 94:0c:6d:f7:66:b4 (try 1/3)
[ 4697.017342] wlxd46e0e1f1528: authenticated
[ 4702.018559] wlxd46e0e1f1528: aborting authentication with 94:0c:6d:f7:66:b4 by local choice (Reason: 3=DEAUTH_LEAVING)
[ 4714.018624] wlxd46e0e1f1528: authenticate with 94:0c:6d:f7:66:b4
[ 4714.048511] wlxd46e0e1f1528: send auth to 94:0c:6d:f7:66:b4 (try 1/3)
[ 4714.052990] wlxd46e0e1f1528: authenticated
[ 4719.049890] wlxd46e0e1f1528: aborting authentication with 94:0c:6d:f7:66:b4 by local choice (Reason: 3=DEAUTH_LEAVING)
[ 4721.154356] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlxd46e0e1f1528: link is not ready
[ 4721.175754] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlxd46e0e1f1528: link is not ready
```

Установил регион `iw reg get`:

```
global
country UA: DFS-ETSI
    (2400 - 2483 @ 40), (N/A, 20), (N/A), NO-OUTDOOR
    (5150 - 5250 @ 80), (N/A, 20), (N/A), NO-OUTDOOR, AUTO-BW
    (5250 - 5350 @ 80), (N/A, 20), (0 ms), NO-OUTDOOR, DFS, AUTO-BW
    (5490 - 5670 @ 160), (N/A, 20), (0 ms), DFS
    (5735 - 5835 @ 80), (N/A, 20), (N/A)
    (57000 - 66000 @ 2160), (N/A, 40), (N/A)
```

А также пробовал отключать IPV6 в графическом интерфейсе NetworkManager, не помогло.
Ещё загружался с флешки в Linux Mint и Ubuntu, там все работает.
Как заставить адаптер работать в Debian?

Comment: Добрый день! Попробуйте сохранить файл /etc/systemd/network/99-default.link и выполнить ln -s /dev/null /etc/systemd/network/99-default.link (это решение если  устройство имеет слишком длинное именя в вашем случае wlxd46e0e1f1528).

Comment: Большое спасибо. Помогло. Можете оформить как ответ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Драйвер устройства создает слишком длинное имя устройства в системе (пример. wlxd46e0e1f1528) И linux некорректно с ним работает (например подключается, а ip получить не может). Как вариант решения проблемы:

```
ln -s /dev/null /etc/systemd/network/99-default.link
```